# Writing JTextArea content into file

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea

I have one JTextArea and a Submit button in Java Swing.
Need to write the content of textarea into a file with line breaks.
I got the output like, it is written as one string in the file.

```
try {
    BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename.txt")); 
    String myString1 =jTextArea1.getText();
    String myString2 = myString1.replace("\r", "\n");

    System.out.println(myString2);

    fileOut.write(myString2);
    fileOut.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please get me some suggestions

Comment: @Charles: am trying to learn new things :-)

Comment: -1 for no research effort. Answer was found on google in 5 seconds.

Comment: I'm just curious: what happens if you just write the String to a file?

Answer (score 18):

Why not use `JTextArea`'s built in [`write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write%28java.io.Writer%29) function?

```
JTextArea area = ...
try (BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(yourFile))) {
    area.write(fileOut);
}
```

Comment: +1 interesting! This is the first time I know about this method.

Answer (score 2):

Replace all \r and \n with:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

This will make your code platform-independent and will write new lines to the files where necessary.

Edit: since you use BufferedWriter, you could also use the [newLine() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Why did you replace `\r` by `\n` ?

The line separator should be `"\r\n"`.

Comment: The line separator is actually platform dependent. Depending on the underlying system, it could be `\r\n`, `\n\r`, `\n` or `\r`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i thought up of :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
BufferedWriter writer;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("SimpleText.txt",
                    false));
            text.write(writer);
            writer.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File has been saved","File Saved",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            // true for rewrite, false for override

        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Occured");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps