# How to use getText() method on a textarea and write to txt file as it appears in textarea?

Tags: java, save, jtextarea

Hi I am trying to use the `getText()` method from a `JTextArea` and write that into a `.txt` file. Here is my code:

```
try {
     String = "OrderDetails.txt";
     PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(fileName);
     output.println("Customer Details");
     // this part is not important
     output.println(txtAreaOutput.getText()); //Spits out multiple lines into a single line :(
     output.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(FamousFavoriteSubs.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

As you can imagine the textarea has multiple rows text and I want to maintain that when I save the text to the .txt file. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The `JTextArea` has a "write" function to which you have to send a `BufferedWriter`.

Actually this was answered multiple times, so please google the problem before posting here.

[Writing JTextArea content into file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522022/writing-jtextarea-content-into-file)

Comment: For a complete working example that both reads and writes the file check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880169/loading-a-text-file-into-a-textarea/5887380#5887380